# Fubini–Tonelli theorem

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

By Fubini-Tonelli theorem, if one of $\int(\int  |f(x,y)| dy)dx$, $\int(\int  |f(x,y)| dx)dy$, $\int\int  |f(x,y)| dxdy$ is finite , then $\int(\int  f(x,y) dy)dx = \int(\int  f(x,y) dx)dy=\int \int  f(x,y) dxdy$. Does this imply that the following cases are impossible,

(i)Both of the iterated integrals exist and agree but the double integral does not exist.

(ii)At least one of the iterated integrals is finite but they are not equal.

Comment: If one of those things on your first line is finite, then both your cases are impossible.  It doesn't say what happens when those things on your first line are infinite.

Comment: @GEdgar So if one of the iterated integral is finite then the double integral has to exist? What about $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$?

Comment: @user136592 The integral is not absolutely convergent. To see, calculate it e.g. over the upper half square $\int_0^1\int_0^y...dxdy$.

Comment: @A.G. But the iterated integrals exist and agree in this case  right?

Comment: @user136592 Even iterated integrals are not agree here: they have the opposite signs $\int\int...dydx=\pi/4$, $\int\int...dxdy=-\pi/4$.

Comment: @A.G. You are right, but since at least one of the integrated integral is finite, don't we conclude that the double integral exists by the theorem?

Comment: @user136592 No, the assumption is that the integral of $|f(x,y)|$ must be finite. The **absolute value is important**. Existence for simply $f$ is too weak (unless $f$ is positive (Tonelli's theorem), but it is not the case here.).

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258465/iterated-integrals-counterexample-to-fubinis-theorem?rq=1

Comment: @A.G. I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another important assumption is that $f$ should be measurable (with respect to the product sigma algebra).