# Why does Fubini's theorem not hold here?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have shown that $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dx  dy=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ and that $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy   dx =-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Shouldn't these two Integrals be equal according to fubini's theorem?

Why do we get two different results?

Comment: Because the integrand is [not integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions).

Comment: Fubini's theorem does hold here; it applies to functions in $L^1(\Bbb R^2)$ of which this is not one.

Comment: @user296602 Why is the function not integrable?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258465/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply Fubini's theorem you would need **absolute** integrability.

However,

$$\int_{[0,1]^2} \left|\frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \right| > \int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{r^2|\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta|}{r^4|\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta|^2}\, r\, dr\, d\theta \\= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_\delta ^1\frac{dr}{r}\int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta| \, d\theta,$$

and

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_\delta ^1\frac{dr}{r} = -\lim_{\delta \to 0} \log \delta = +\infty$$

Comment: Absolute integrability is needed when the integrand takes both positive and negative values. When it takes only positive values the order of integration can always be changed.