# How does one check the integral condition of Fubini's?

Tags: fubini-tonelli-theorems

How does one check the integral condition of Fubini's?

I.e. that

$$\int_{A \times B} |f(x,y)|d(x,y) < \infty$$

Isn't the use of Fubini's to avoid having to calculate this?

I don't understand how to calculate such integral w/o iterated.

Comment: You calculate it with tonellis theorem.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Okay so, Tonelli requires that $f$ from $X \times Y$ to $[0, \infty]$ is non-negative measurable. And then the integral equals the iterated. So this reason's "backwards" to the assumption of Fubini's? Or  you suggest to replace Fubini's with Tonelli's.

Comment: $|f|$ is non-negative and measurable (if $f$ is measurable).

Comment: What i'm saying is.
Use Tonellis theorem on $|f|$ to check that the condition
$$\int_{A\times B} |f(x,y)| d(x,y) < \infty$$
is satisfied. Afterwards you can use fubinis to compute
$$\int_{A\times B} f(x,y) d(x,y)$$

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen But I don't understand how to compute that integral w/o being able to split it to iterated ones.

Comment: What is your objective here? Determine if $f$ is absolutely integrable (thereby meeting the conditions of Fubini's theorem) so that you can then do ... what? Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @RRL Fubini's says that one must check that the prior integral is finite, before being able to apply Fubini's. The problem may be, how to check it (w/o being able to resort to iterated integrals).

Comment: OK so to ascertain that $\int_{A \times B} |f| < \infty$ without actually evaluating. Often that can be done by a comparison test.

Comment: @RRL I saw an example that did that by fixing or "parametrizing along" the other variable so that a $\mathbb{R}^2$ integral becomes $\int_{min_y}^{max_y} |f| dy$.

Comment: It really depends on the specific structure. An example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2456906/148510

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(A,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $(B,\mathcal{N},\nu)$, and a measurable function $f:A\times B \to \Bbb{C}$. To check the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem, we usually apply Tonelli's theorem to guarantee that $f$ is integrable (with repsect to the product measure).

Tonelli's theorem tells us that if $\phi:A\times B \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable (relative to the appropriate $\sigma$-algebras) then you can always iterate the integrals and the result is always the same:
\begin{align}
\int_{A\times B}\phi(x,y)\, d(x,y) = \int_A \int_B \phi(x,y)\, dy \, dx = \int_B \int_A \phi(x,y)\, dx \, dy
\end{align}
Just to be more explicit, this says all three terms are finite and equal, or they are all equal to $\infty$.

So, with this in mind, to check the hypothesis $\int_{A\times B}|f(x,y)| \,d(x,y)< \infty$ which is required for Fubini's theorem, we first apply Tonelli's theorem:
\begin{align}
\int_{A\times B}|f(x,y)|\, d(x,y) = \int_A \int_B |f(x,y)|\, dy \, dx = \int_B \int_A |f(x,y)|\, dx \, dy \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Out of these three, calculate whichever integral is the easiest to do (after all, they are all equal). If it is finite, great! Fubini's theorem's hypotheses are satisfied so you can remove absolute values and say that
\begin{align}
\int_{A\times B}f(x,y)\, d(x,y) = \int_A \int_B f(x,y)\, dy \, dx = \int_B \int_A f(x,y)\, dx \, dy
\end{align}
If however $(*)$ results in $\infty$, then that is very unfortunate, and you have to be very careful in your subsequent analysis.